# Laravel: Changes to vue js components are not displayed in production

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am developing an application using Laravel and Vue. 
From the local I made some changes on vue components and then after running the **npm run production** command I uploaded to the webserver in production.
Unfortunately the changes are not displayed. If I then delete the component folders inside resource/js/ the contents components are still displayed...is it a cache problem? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: is there anything in your gitignore says `public/js`? If not probably @brokedid's answer should help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to apply [Versioning](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/versioning) to the javascript files.

So adding:

`mix.version()`

at the end of the `webpack.mix.js` file and then including the JS-Files with

`{{ mix('js/my-js-file-name.js') }}`

it sould add a Version-String at the end of the Filename (before: `my-js-file-name.js`, after: `my-js-file-name.js?v=12345`) and then bypassing the cache of a CDN / Webhosting-Provider or other Cache what may be in between.